# Translate this float value into english

Tags: c++, visual-studio, floating-point

So I was debugging in VS and I found this to be the value of a float variable

> -1.#INF0000

What is it? negative infinity? If not then what's the INF mean?

Comment: My guess is that you are probably dividing by zero somewhere.

Comment: Your number probably is one of [those](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isinf). You certainly have a textual representation, not the actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is negative infinity.

To be sure, you could test it against:
[float.isNegativeInfinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.isnegativeinfinity(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Provided link is related to .NET Framework / Common Language Runtime. You can not use it in C++ unless you write a .NET program in C++. Universal way to do it across all modern C++ implementations is to use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/). This class template has specializations for each generic type in implementation, and `float` specialization will have a specific member `infinity`, which is responsible for representing positive infinity in `float`'s format.

Answer (score 1):

This is a string representation of a floating-point number value for negative infinity.

Strings may be different for different compilers and libraries. Consult this:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2022.pdf

Comment: Negative infinity is not a NaN value